# Not displaying images in Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I know this question has been asked many times, but I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. I have the images folder under the src/main/webapp folder (this a maven web project). I have the index.jsp in the src/main/webapp/WEBINF/views folder.

I'm trying to access the images and other resources like css and js like this:

`<img src="/images/left_arrow.png" alt="" />`

But the images are not getting displayed.

Here is the web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is the WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ravi.WebApp" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Here is the Controller
    package com.ravi.WebApp;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String printWelcome(Model model) {
    return "index";

}

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding the following resources declaration to your Spring configuration:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /images/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/images directory -->
<resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

Alternatively, and more common, is to have a `resources` folder which contains all your resources (images, css, js, etc...), broken out by sub-directories.

Your configuration would then look like:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And your resources would be referenced as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/screen.css" />" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" />"></script>
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/left_arrow.png" />" alt="" />
```

Comment: I'm getting this error after adding the resources declaration in Spring Configuration " No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WebApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'"

Comment: It worked. The change I made is I refered the images in the jsp using c:url tag <img src="<c:url value='/resources/images/ip_banner.jpg" />" alt="" />. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If Using annotation then make sure to user

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

with resources

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

else annotaion controller will not work

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a reference your image folder on Spring MVC configuration file

WEB-INF/spring-context.xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/*" location="/images/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps in this picture.. :)

Step 1: Create a folder in webapp but not in WEB-INF

> Create Resources then images then store your image.
>   webapp/resources/images/fileName.jpg

Step 2: Now that you have created your folders

> Let us map the path you created in the servlet configuration file where we deal with mapping of the paths 
>         Add this code : 
>       `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/*" location="/resources/" />`

Step 3:
Add the code for accessing the image resource from the location you created in step 1: 
     `<img src="/attendance/resources/images/logo.png"  width="100px" height="100px">`

[image: Spring MVC access Image in JSP]

Comment: it might be useful if you could briefly describe each step.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the static resources outside the WEB-INF folders in your web root and want the container to handle the static resource requests, you should add this to your application context file:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

The suggestion by @BeauGrantham to add resources mapping will also work.

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestions worked for me as well.  But if anyone else has trouble with the associated namespace, I had to add the mvc portion to `mvc-dispatcher-serlvet.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd ">

...

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```