# Image not showing up in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring mvc, I have successfully setup a welcome page but the image that I have added in it not displaying, after reading lots of articles I have managed to modify my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml 
like below

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.diluks.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

and my index.jsp page is like below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${welcomemessage}</h1>
<img alt="Image" src="/resources/images/testimage.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

It gives me the Welcome Message correctly but it does not display the image. Please help me on this.

Comment: did you inspect your browser? what is the src of the img in the browser?

Comment: it says <img alt="Image" src="/resources/images/testimage.jpg">

Comment: Try to change your code jsp like ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/testimage.jpg and see what your are getting in the browser.

Comment: Now its giving me <img alt="Image" src="/MyWebApp/resources/images/testimage.jpg"> but still no image displaying

Comment: Can you try hitting the image url directly into the browser. yourDomain/MyWebApp/resources/images/testimage.jpg and check if the image is loaded or not.

Comment: No, it doesn't load, gives me HTTP Status 404 - /resources/images/testimage.jpg

Comment: Please do check the following post,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847247/not-displaying-images-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Looks like your image is not available in the server. Check the image path with the directory structure. Here is an tutorial to load static files using spring framework. http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Answer (score 2):

Change image src attributes value to following :

```
<img alt="Image" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/testimage.jpg">
```

Give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

If your using JSTL, try

```
<img alt="Image" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/testimage.jpg"/>"/>
```

If you are not using, then you can try

```
<img alt="Image" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/testimage.jpg"/>
```